# Add codeigniter php data to Chart js

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter, chart.js

in my view im getting data as key and value for display in a chart

```
<?php foreach ($statistics as $key=>$stat):?>
  <?php echo $key?>
  <?php echo $stat?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

**$statistics** have a data set like below

> Array ( [09-11-2018] => 1 [10-11-2018] => 2 [11-11-2018] => 5 ) Array
>   ( [09-11-2018] => 1 [10-11-2018] => 2 [11-11-2018] => 5 )

**chart js script like below**

```
<script>
    var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");

    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'line',
            data: {
                  labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
                  datasets: [{
                        label: 'Users',
                        data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3]
                             }]
                  },
            options: {
            scales: {
                  yAxes: [{
                        ticks: {
                             beginAtZero:true
                               }
                          }]
                    }
           }
       });
  </script>
```

how can i add labels as **$key** data and dataset data as **$stat** data

please help me with this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your code with below code

```
foreach ($statistics as $key=>$stat){
  $label[]=$key;
  $data[]=$stat;
}
```

And script code

```
<script>
  var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");
  var labelData='<?php echo json_encode($label); ?>';
  var chartData='<?php echo json_encode($data); ?>'
  var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'line',
        data: {
              labels: labelData,
              datasets: [{
                    label: 'Users',
                    data: chartData
                         }]
              },
        options: {
        scales: {
              yAxes: [{
                    ticks: {
                         beginAtZero:true
                           }
                      }]
                }
       }
   });
</script>
```